# Pregunta básica sobre getopts

Tags: bash, scripting

Soy un completo principiante y no tengo ni idea de por que esto no funciona.
Es un script muy básico cuyo objetivo es descargar un archivo y mostrar algunos datos relacionados con este. Va así.

```
!#/bin/bash
wget https://query.data.world/s/dcgqoxjg7ttuq4xlxlcdgjwfjjkayq -O pokedex.csv
url="https://query.data.world/s/dcgqoxjg7ttuq4xlxlcdgjwfjjkayq"
col="13"
fil="1072"
form="CSV"
echo "La URL de descarga es: $url"
echo "El fichero contiene $col columnas"
echo "El fichero contiene $fil filas"
while getopts ":v:" option; do
case "$option" in
v)
echo "El fichero esta en formato: $form"
csvstat pokedex.csv
;;
esac
done
```

El objetivo es que cuando haga la invocación de -v imprima datos extra y cuando no, solo los mencionados antes del *loop* de *while*.
De momento lo único que consigo es que o bien solo imprima los datos de antes del *loop* o bien me lo imprima todo haga lo que haga ( lo he intentado haciendo un montaje con *if* )

Comment: Si solo necesitas pasarle un parámetro sin argumentos no necesitas `getops`.  Con un `case $1 in` tienes suficiente para interpretarlo.  ¿Eso te serviria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lo que estas pidiendo, creo que tu script en bash podria quedar asi:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget https://query.data.world/s/dcgqoxjg7ttuq4xlxlcdgjwfjjkayq -O pokedex.csv
url="https://query.data.world/s/dcgqoxjg7ttuq4xlxlcdgjwfjjkayq"
col="13"
fil="1072"
form="CSV"
echo "La URL de descarga es: $url"
echo "El fichero contiene $col columnas"
echo "El fichero contiene $fil filas"
case "$1" in
  "-v")
    echo "El fichero esta en formato: $form"
    csvstat pokedex.csv
  ;;
  *)
    echo "Para información ampliada ejecuta este comando con el parámetro -v"
  ;;
esac
```

***Cambios realizados:***

1. He corregido la primera línea. Tenias el `Shebang` (`#!`) puesto al reves.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   ```
2. He quitado el `while` con la línea del `getops` porque no estas usando argumentos.
3. He modificado el `case` para pasarle tu primer parámetro del script representado por `$1`.  Si tuvieras dos parámetros serian representados por `$1` y `$2`, etc.

   ```
   case "$1" in
   ```
4. He puesto como posible caso el parámetro que pides, `-v` con sus instrucciones a continuación y luego lo he cerrado con `;;`.

   ```
   "-v")
     echo "El fichero esta en formato: $form"
     csvstat pokedex.csv
   ;;
   ```
5. He agregado un caso por defecto, representado por `*` para que muestre información ampliada, en este caso la sintaxis del parámetro existente actual.

   ```
   *)
     echo "Para información ampliada ejecuta este comando con el parámetro -v"
   ;;
   ```

Si no le pasas ningun parámetro al script o éste no existe entonces mostrará esa información contenida en el caso `*`.